# Aggregation sum Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate-functions

I have the following dataframe

How can I aggregate the number of tickets (summing) for every month?
I tried:

```
df_res[df_res["type"]=="other"].groupby(["type","date"])["n_tickets"].sum()
```

date is an object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need assign to new `DataFrame` for same size of `Series` created by [`Series.dt.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.month.html):

```
#if necessary convert to datetimes
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df = df_res[df_res["type"]=="pax"]
#type is same, so should be omited
out = df.groupby(df["date"].dt.month)["n_tickets"].sum()
#if need column with same value `pax`
#out = df.groupby(['type',df["date"].dt.month])["n_tickets"].sum()
```

If want grouping by `pax` and `no pax`:

```
types = np.where(df_res["type"]=="pax", 'pax', 'no pax')
df_res.groupby([types, df_res["date"].dt.month])["n_tickets"].sum()
```

Comment: maybe add `df.date=pd.to_datetime(df.date)`

Comment: Can it be used for both times without separating? pax and other?

Comment: It is working. I am just trying to make more uses of it

Comment: do you think `pax` and all another values?